# inherit from inner class and pass it in on outer template simultaneously?

Tags: c++11, templates, inner-classes

I'm trying to create a tree structure where the user can make their own tree node inheritor, but the node encapsulates some code for managing its position in the tree and exposing children to inheritors. I have code similar to this:

```
template <typename TData>
class TreeBase {
protected:
    struct TreeNode { // should be fully encapsulated
        TData data;
        ...
    };
public: ...
};

template <typename TNode>
struct Tree: public TreeBase<TNode> {
    class Node {
        typename TreeBase<TNode>::TreeNode _tn; // keep encapsulated
    public: ...
    };
    ...
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Node, TNode>::value, "TNode must be a descendant of NodeTrie::Node");
};
```

And though the class definitions compile, I can't figure out how to use them. I can't make an inheritor of Node without putting that inside an inheritor of Tree, and I can't make an inheritor of Tree without passing in my node type. It's a chicken & egg problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: From the static assert (`is_base_of<Node, TNode>`)  follow that you want user types to inherit from tree node type (`struct A : Tree<A>::Node {};`). Why would you want that?

Comment: I do want that inheritance. The public methods on `Node` are useful and necessary for some computations on the tree.

Comment: You have a recursion, you want `A` to inherit from `Tree<A>::Node`, which contains `TreeBase<A>::TreeNode`, which contains `A`.

Comment: Yes, I have a recursion problem. I'm looking for some alternative strategies.

Comment: What prevents you from not storing `TData` in `TreeNode`? Your tree will store `TNode` elements directly.

Comment: You have `Node`, `TNode` and `TreeNode`, with the user having no clear idea of which is doing what. Invest in better names.